# Running Drupal in Docker container

Tags: drupal, docker

I want to run a Drupal website in a docker container but everytime i change the web folder in the drupal container into a volume i run into issues.

```
docker run --name some-drupal -v /data/web:/var/www/html -p 8080:80 -d drupal
```

If I use a volume the website won't load anymore and refuses the connection.

I'm using [this respository for my drupal](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/tree/865f61938fe7f37359d8feeb13bb03bff8f11387) image.

Comment: can you maybe show the docker logs. Your app is in /data/web folder on your host +  has it an index.php (html) page?

Comment: @lorenzvth7 here is a dump of the container log http://pastebin.com/x7rP3FAK . When a open it in the webbrowser I get 403 Forbidden no access.

Comment: Do you have an indexpage (index.php or index.html)?

Comment: No nothing the var/www/html folder is empty.

Comment: Performing 'cat /data/web' gives you your webapp on the host? I tried the drupal image and my stuff is loaded into the /var/www/html of the container

Comment: What os do you use? I thought it could be an issue with Windows, but trired it worked for me even without having the folder. So my guess it´s something with the os or access to the folder